# How to remove Disk 0 when Windows is installed in Disk 1?

Tags: windows-7, boot

I did a clean install of Windows 7 Ultimate x64 on a brand new hard disk that I installed in my machine and kept my existing Vista install intact. Windows 7 was installed on Disk 1, which it labeled c:. The old hard disk is listed as Disk 0, (System, Active, Primary Partition) and when I boot up I can choose which OS to boot, Vista or Windows 7, so I assume that it looks on that drive on startup.

I would now like to remove that old Drive. What steps would be required so that my computer will still be able to boot when I remove Disk 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can look at my earlier answer to a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/18900/vista-windows-7-dual-boot-format-vista-partition/18908#18908). The same steps apply just replace paragraph one with "yank out drive 0"